# Is there the parameter to pass a billing address to "Payments" on Stripe Dashboard after a payment on Stripe Checkout?

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments, checkout

I'm trying to pass a billing address to **Payments** on **Stripe Dashboard** but I couldn't find the parameter to do it in [payment_intent_data](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data).

So instead, I used [payment_intent_data.metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-metadata) as shown below. *I use Django:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import redirect
import stripe

checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
    line_items=[
        {
            "price_data": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "unit_amount_decimal": 1000,
                "product_data": {
                    "name": "T-shirt"
                },
            },
            "quantity": 2
        }
    ],
    payment_intent_data={
        "shipping":{
            "name": "John Smith",
            "phone": "14153758094",
            "address":{
                "country": "USA",
                "state": "California",
                "city": "San Francisco",
                "line1": "58 Middle Point Rd",
                "line2": "",
                "postal_code": "94124"
            }
        },
        "metadata":{  # Here
            "name": "Anna Brown",
            "phone": "19058365484",
            "country": "Canada",
            "state": "Ontario",
            "city": "Newmarket",
            "line1": "3130 Leslie Street",
            "line2": "",
            "postal_code": "L3Y 2A3"
        }
    },
    mode='payment',
    success_url='http://localhost:8000',
    cancel_url='http://localhost:8000'
)
return redirect(checkout_session.url, code=303)
```

Then, I could pass a billing address to **Payments** on **Stripe Dashboard** as shown below, but if there is the parameter to pass a billing address to **Payments** on **Stripe Dashboard**, it is really useful:

[image]

I know that there are [address](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create#create_customer-address) parameter when [creating a customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create) and [address](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-address) parameter when [updating a customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update) but both `address` doesn't have `name` and `phone` parameters.

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import redirect
import stripe

def test(request):
    customer = stripe.Customer.search(query="email:'test@gmail.com'", limit=1)
    
    shipping={
        "name": "John Smith",
        "phone": "14153758094",
        "address":{
            "country": "USA",
            "state": "CA",
            "city": "San Francisco",
            "line1": "58 Middle Point Rd",
            "line2": "",
            "postal_code": "94124"
        }
    }

    address={ # Here
        "country": "Canada",
        "state": "Ontario",
        "city": "Newmarket",
        "line1": "3130 Leslie Street",
        "line2": "",
        "postal_code": "L3Y 2A3"
    }

    if customer['data']:
        customer = stripe.Customer.modify(
            customer['data'][0]['id'],
            name="John Smith",
            shipping=shipping,
            address=address # Here
        )
    else:
        customer = stripe.Customer.create( 
            name="John Smith",
            shipping=shipping,
            address=address # Here
        )

    checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        customer=customer["id"],
        line_items=[
            {
                "price_data": {
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "unit_amount_decimal": 1000,
                    "product_data": {
                        "name": "T-shirt"
                    },
                },
                "quantity": 2
            }
        ],
        mode='payment',
        success_url='http://localhost:8000',
        cancel_url='http://localhost:8000'
    )
```

And, a billing address is passed to **Customers** as **Billing details** but not to **Payments** on **Stripe Dashboard** as shown below which means each payment in **Payments** cannot have a specific billing address:

[image]

Now, is there the parameter to pass a billing address to **Payments** on **Stripe Dashboard** after a payment on **Stripe Checkout**?

And, if not, will **Stripe** add `billing_address` parameter to `payment_intent_data`?

Answer (score 0):

A PaymentIntent object doesn't have `billing_details` hash, perhaps what you refer to is the [billing_details](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-billing_details) from a PaymentMethod object?

There's no option to set a `billing_details` for a PaymentMethod during CheckoutSession creation, but you can listen to `checkout.session.completed` event, and retrieve the PaymentMethod object from `checkout_session->payment_intent->payment_method` and call the [Update API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/update#update_payment_method-billing_details) to update its `billing_details`